# How can I tell when Safari on iPad is using HTTPS

Tags: ipad, ios, mobile-safari

Safari hides the protocol part of the URL (HTTP or HTTPS) in the address bar.

When I'm purchasing something on the Internet, I like to check that I'm using HTTPS when entering credit card details or entering a username and password.

I don't seem to be able to do this when using Safari on my iPad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There should be a padlock before the page title at the top of the screen when you're on an https page.

Answer (score 1):

On iPad 3 I touch the address bar to select then touch and hold to bring up the magnifying glass. Move your finger to the left all the way past the www.  To reveal https:// or http://

Answer (score -1):

you should see a locked lock near the type address, it shows that you are on https connection